# ASP.NET Membership: Login Controls Source Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, visual-studio-2005, forms-authentication

Is the source code for the common login controls available?

Those are the controls which are available under Login section in Toolbox:

- Login,
- LoginView,
- PasswordRecovery,
- LoginStatus,
- LoginName,
- CreateUserWizard,
- ChangePassword

Eventually could you point me to a good source of custom implementation of functionality that those controls provide, or some guidance on implementing this functionality without using the mentioned controls.

I am using Visual Studio 2005 (.net2)

I will be using SQLMembershipProvider as the MembershipProvider but that probably should make no difference.

Comment: Try this [blog by Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give this a qualified "NO".

I have gone down the road of implementing an implementation of the Login server control using reflected source as a starting point (this was before symbol server integration).

Things seem to go swimmingly, with a few reflection hacks to get to core framework members that obviate reams of code.

Until you get to the designers.  That infrastructure is a minefield and gets wide and deep with a quickness and is filled with even deeper buried internal types that need implementations or reflection hacks.

Ultimately wound up with a working control that I could extend but would never want to maintain.

The effort was not wasted; I learned a lot about how over engineered server controls are designed.

And then I just shifted a login control to template mode and got everything I needed to get done in a few lines of code. ;-)

Except as a learning experience I would certainly recommend against going down that road.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, it good to see people answering some old questions, hopefully it will help someone in the future. And yes, I ended up using template back then as well :)

Answer (score 3):

"the entire framework is available" is not true. :)

Comment: +1 - not looking at it directly at the moment but I think this is going to be one of the holes.

Answer (score 2):

The source code for the entire framework is available. The link below provides some details as to how to access:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: You need to qualify this answer: The SYMBOLS are downloaded upon demand. The actual source files are not made available until you either break on an exception in framework code or explicitly STEP INTO a framework member. Only then will the source file open in VS. After that you can find the source files in a directory next to the symbols.